# Lock Parted Magic?

Tags: lock

Is it possible to lock the [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) screen so that others don't tamper with it while it's in the middle of long operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Parted Magic 2013.08.01, right click an empty spot on Desktop and
select Lock Screen

password = partedmagic

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen a way to accomplish this. If you're that concerned I would just unplug the keyboard during this portion of the Parted Magic run and plug it back in when you're ready to proceed.

Comment: Although this isn't really an "answer," I'm still accepting it because I've decided to ask for this as a feature request in the Parted Magic forums (http://forums.partedmagic.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5060).

Comment: I've +1 your feature request. I'd never thought of this feature being added until you asked but I think it would be a nice one to have.